# DAX Related() with Many to Many relationship in Power BI

Tags: sorting, powerbi, tooltip

I have a model where we need to sort the legend column based on Total sum of a column
My Line graph uses Quarter and Total in the axis.Category is used as Legend.Graph is sorted by Quarter in Ascending Order.
Now i want the Tool tip to be sorted by Total Alerts .Tool Tip shows Category value and Total .
For each quarter category value may be different 
For Eg :
Q1:
Bus : 1
Car : 2

Q4:
Bus : 7
Car 6

So based on this my Tool tip should be sorted in Descending order automatically.When i Tried  Related () i am able to sort based on category but based on quarter level i am not able to sort

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the "Sort on" functionality ? If you select the column you want sorted, in the "Column help"(might be called differently in english, my power bi is set to Dutch) you can find "sort on". From here you should be able to sort on quarter (if your quarter column is in the same Query as the column you want sorted). You could also create a "sort" Column on which you could sort in the same fashion. (i.e. 1 for the data you want first, 2 for second, etc..)

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld  Thanks for your reply.As mentioned earlier , i am trying this on a Line chart where axis is Quarter and Value is the Total.And Legend is the Funnel Sub category .so i am not able to sort on the Legend.When i try to add the column to tool tip for sorting , then the tool tip becomes ambiguous.